# Passing a two dimensional array by reference in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I need help with a homework problem.

The description of the homework is:

> Design a program in C, using the method of call by reference, which
>   generates statistics on the grades in a class consisting of M students
>   and N quizzes given during the course of a semester. The quizzes all
>   carry equal weighting, with the grade in each quiz being out of 10
>   points. The program is to do the following in the indicated sequence
>   when the program is executed:
>
> 1. Ask the user to type on the keyboard the number of number of students M and the number of quizzes N, with M representing the number
>      of rows and N representing the number of columns  in a two-dimensional
>      array x[M][N] of floating-point numbers.
> 2. Ask the user to type on the keyboard the values of all the elements of the array x[M][N].
> 3. Display on the console the M rows and N columns of inputted array element values.
> 4. Generate and display on the console the elements of a one-dimensional array p[M] where each element of this array p[M]
>      represents the average grade over the semester of each of the M
>      students.
> 5. Generate and display on the console the elements of a one-dimensional array q[N] where each element of q[N] represents the
>      average grade in the class in each of the N quizzes .
> 6. Generate and display on the console the average grade z for the entire class over the entire semester.

This is the code that I've done so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define students 300
#define quizzes 20

void averageGradeOfStudents(int M, int N, float p[], float *xPtr);
float averageGradeOfClass();
float averageGradeOfWholeClass();

int main() {
    int M, N;
    float x[students][quizzes];

    printf("Enter the number students (Maximum: 300): ");
    scanf_s("%d", &M);

    printf("\nEnter the number of Quizzes (Maximum: 20): ");
    scanf_s("%d", &N);

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
    printf("Enter the grade for student %d, Quiz %d: ", i, k);
            scanf_s("%f", &x[i][k]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n");

    for (int k = 1; k <= N; k++) {
        printf("\t\tQuiz%d", k);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        printf("\nStudent%d Grades: ", i);
        for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
            printf("%.2f\t\t", x[i][k]);
        }

    }
    printf("\n\n\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n");

    float p[students];
    averageGradeOfStudents(M, N, p, &x[0][0]);

    float q[quizzes];

    float z;

    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void averageGradeOfStudents(int M, int N, float p[], float *xPtr) {
    float grade[students];

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
            grade[i] += *(xPtr + i);
        }
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < M; k++) {
        p[k] = grade[k] / N;
        printf("The average grade of student%d is: %.2f\n\n", k, p[k]);
    }    
}
float averageGradeOfClass() {



}

float averageGradeOfWholeClass() {



}
```

The problem I'm having is that I can't figure out a way to sum each row of the array individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very good progress on your assignment. It is refreshing to get full code and effort. There are a couple of things that will help before we get to an average. First, and always good practice, *initialize your variables*. This is especially true with arrays as it prevents an accidental attempt to read from an uninitialized value, and in the case of character arrays can provide automatic *null-termination* for the first copy to the array (as long as you only copy size-1 chars).

```
    int M = 0, N = 0;
    float x[students][quizzes] = {{ 0 }};
    float p[students] = {0};
    float q[quizzes] = {0};
    float z = 0;
```

Passing arrays is always a problem area. When passing an array declared as a 2D array, you must pass the width of the array as part of the function argument:

```
void averageGradeOfStudents (int M, int N, float p[], float xPtr[][quizzes]);
```

and then you can simply call the function by passing the array itself.

```
    averageGradeOfStudents (M, N, p, x);
```

(*note:* the first level of indirection of any array is converted to a pointer when passed as a function argument, but that is a topic for a later question. However, for your reference, your function declaration could also be properly written as):

```
void averageGradeOfStudents (int M, int N, float p[], float (*xPtr)[quizzes]);
```

Now on to your average, you were close, you only needed to sum the elements per-student by changing the way you were indexing `xPtr` (and initialize the values of `grade`):

```
void averageGradeOfStudents (int M, int N, float p[], float xPtr[][quizzes]) 
{
    float grade[M];

    /* initialize variable length array to 0 */
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) grade[i] = 0;

    /* sum of grades for each student */
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
            grade[i] += xPtr[i][k];
        }
    }

    printf ("The average grades for the students are:\n\n");
    for (int k = 0; k < M; k++) {
        p[k] = grade[k] / N;
        printf("  student[%3d] is: %6.2f\n", k, p[k]);
    }    
}
```

A quick example of its use in the full-code could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define students 300
#define quizzes 20

void averageGradeOfStudents (int M, int N, float p[], float (*xPtr)[quizzes]);

int main (void) {

    /* good habit -- always initialize your variables */
    int M = 0, N = 0;
    float x[students][quizzes] = {{ 0 }};
    float p[students] = {0};

    printf("Enter the number students (Maximum: 300): ");
    scanf ("%d", &M);

    printf("\nEnter the number of Quizzes (Maximum: 20): ");
    scanf ("%d", &N);

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
            printf("Enter the grade for student %d, Quiz %d: ", i, k);
            scanf("%f", &x[i][k]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n");

    printf ("                        ");
    for (int k = 1; k <= N; k++) {
        printf(" Quiz%-2d", k);
    }
    putchar ('\n');

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        printf("\n  Student[%3d] Grades: ", i);
        for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
            printf(" %6.2f", x[i][k]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n");

    averageGradeOfStudents (M, N, p, x);

    /* getchar(); */
    return 0;
}

void averageGradeOfStudents (int M, int N, float p[], float (*xPtr)[quizzes]) 
{
    float grade[M];

    /* initialize variable length array to 0 */
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) grade[i] = 0;

    /* sum of grades for each student */
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
            grade[i] += xPtr[i][k];
        }
    }

    printf ("The average grades for the students are:\n\n");
    for (int k = 0; k < M; k++) {
        p[k] = grade[k] / N;
        printf("  student[%3d] is: %6.2f\n", k, p[k]);
    }
    putchar ('\n');
}
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/studentavg
Enter the number students (Maximum: 300): 3

Enter the number of Quizzes (Maximum: 20): 3
Enter the grade for student 0, Quiz 0: 8
Enter the grade for student 0, Quiz 1: 9
Enter the grade for student 0, Quiz 2: 8
Enter the grade for student 1, Quiz 0: 9
Enter the grade for student 1, Quiz 1: 9
Enter the grade for student 1, Quiz 2: 10
Enter the grade for student 2, Quiz 0: 7
Enter the grade for student 2, Quiz 1: 8
Enter the grade for student 2, Quiz 2: 9

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                         Quiz1  Quiz2  Quiz3

  Student[  0] Grades:    8.00   9.00   8.00
  Student[  1] Grades:    9.00   9.00  10.00
  Student[  2] Grades:    7.00   8.00   9.00

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

The average grades for the students are:

  student[  0] is:   8.33
  student[  1] is:   9.33
  student[  2] is:   8.00
```

**Note:** I've changed `scanf_s` to `scanf` for my system, you will need to change it back. Let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 2):

I would not declare the array until you know the values of M and N. So the first part of `main` would be as shown below. (This also allows you to dump the `students` and `quizzes` constants.) And always check the return values from library functions.

```
int main( void )
{
    int M, N;

    printf("Enter the number students (Maximum: 300): ");
    if ( scanf_s("%d", &M) != 1 || M > 300 ) {
        printf( "Whatever\n" );
        exit( 1 );
    }

    printf("\nEnter the number of Quizzes (Maximum: 20): ");
    if ( scanf_s("%d", &N) != 1 || N > 20 ) {
        printf( "Sigh...\n" );
        exit( 1 );
    }

    float x[M][N];

    // ...
}
```

When passing an array to a function, you can use array notation. And you're allowed to omit the first dimension of the array. So the following two function declarations are both valid

```
void averageGradeOfStudents(int M, int N, float p[M], float x[M][N]);    
void averageGradeOfStudents(int M, int N, float p[], float x[][N]);
```

Inside the function, there are some problems

- `grade[i]` is not initialized before being used (this should have resulted in a compiler warning)
- Each `grade[i]` should be the averages of N grades (indexed by `k` not `i`)
- You don't really need the `grade` array since you already have the `p` array

Here's how I would write the function (I changed the index names to keep my rows and columns clear)

```
void averageGradeOfStudents(int M, int N, float p[], float x[][N])
{
    for (int row = 0; row < M; row++) {
        p[row] = 0;                         // initialize the sum to zero
        for (int col = 0; col < N; col++) {
            p[row] += x[row][col];          // update the sum with each test result
        }
        p[row] /= N;                        // convert the sum to the average
    }

    for (int row = 0; row < M; row++) {
        printf("The average grade of student%d is: %.2f\n\n", row, p[row]);
    }    
}
```

And the function should be called with

```
averageGradeOfStudents(M, N, p, x);
```

Answer (score 1):

Summing an array is a fairly common idiom:

```
double sumArray(double arr[], int arrLen)
{
    int i;
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (i = 0; i < arrLen; i++)
        sum += arr[i];

    return sum;
}
```

This sums a one-dimension array, but keep in mind that each row of your array `x` is a one-dimension array.

Answer (score 0):

```
int avg=0;
int sum=0;
for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
    printf("Enter the grade for student %d, Quiz %d: ", i, k);
            scanf("%f", &x[i][k]);
            sum=sum+x[i][k]
        }
    }avg=sum/M;
```

as to get avg you have to sum...try this may help you

Comment: Yes, I did it this way originally; but I have to use call by reference method.