# Changing Information in a 2D Array in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is more of a conceptual questions about managing a single 2D array across multiple functions with pointers. What the program boils down to is getting a 2D matrix of characters and then searching that matrix for a specific word.

Here is my approach in two steps:

1) Function that reads in a file char by char, placing all non-space characters into a 2D matrix. Then returning the matrix for manipulation in other places (This is the trouble I'm having)

2) Function that takes the 2D matrix created by 1 and searches for a word

My problem with step one is pointers. I think the best idea would be to create the 2D array in main (I know the max size is 25x25) and pass that pointer so the functions can look through/change the data of the matrix. I simply cant figure out how to modify a 2D array from outside main.

Here is a snipit of my first function and the main I'm using to test it.

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char game[25][25];
    char (*g) = game;
    buildPuzzle(argv[0], g); //game should be a pointer to the array, correct?

    for (int i=0; i<25; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<25; j++) {    
            printf(" %c ", game[i][j]);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }
}

//This function returns a pointer to the array containing the sorted input file

void buildPuzzle(char fileName[], char *puzzle[25][25]){

    int rows = 0;
    int colums = 0;
    char currentChar = NULL;
    //Tests to see if file can open
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if (f == NULL) {
        printf("Can't open file %s\n", fileName);
        exit(420);
    }
    //Scans through the file char by char. 
    //If it is a char it puts it in a row/col of puzzle[][] then goes to the next char by fgetc. 
    currentChar = fgetc(f);
    while(1) {
        if (currentChar = EOF)
            break;
        //If it hits the end of the line, it's time to go to the next row.
        if (currentChar == '\n'){
            rows++;
            continue;
        }
        //Skips spaces
        if (currentChar == ' '){
            continue;
        }
        puzzle[rows][colums] = currentChar;
        currentChar = fgetc(f);
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: What's your question? Is there a problem with the code as it is currently written?

Comment: You will likely find the following helpful [**Passing a two dimensional array by reference in C**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33796210/passing-a-two-dimensional-array-by-reference-in-c/33796961#33796961). It will help you with the basic considerations involved in passing an array between functions.

Comment: `char *puzzle[25][25]` means 625 pointers . This doesn't seem to be what you want.  Also, `char (*g)` means the same as `char *g`.

Comment: Your function does not return anything, as you declared it `void`. But you **could** actually return your array. However, it might be easier and more straight-forward just to pass the array for modification and return a status (e.g. "success"/"fail").

Comment: Also enable compiler warnings and pay heed to them. The compiler is your friend, helping to get types right.

Comment: The compiler is a friend, but for a beginner a friend who speaks a foreign language ;)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `char (*g) = game;`. You could simply call `buildPuzzle(argv[0], game);` and define your function like this:

```
void buildPuzzle(char * fileName, char puzzle[25][25])
{
   // ...
```

You have to include the second dimension of `25` in the `puzzle` parameter, so the compiler knows to skip 25 characters for each increment in the first dimension.